# Find where a function starts and ends to decrease

Tags: python, points, derivative

I have data which describe a series like that:

[image]

I am interested in calculating the points where the strong decreasing starts and ends. Like that:

[image]

So I calcuted the second derivative of my function and get the points when there a negative minima (start decreasing) and a positive maximum.

But what I obtain in the most of cases is similar to that:

[image]

Where am I wrong?

Here there is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# set x and y
y = data_series
x = range(len(data_series)) 

# interpolation
f =  InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y) 

# gen function points
new_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=1000, endpoint=True)
new_y = f(new_x)

# calculate second derivative
y_df1 = np.insert(np.diff(y), 0, 0)
y_df2 = np.insert(np.diff(y_df1), 0, 0) 

# points where the decrease starts and ends
# (where the second derivative is minimum and maximum)
x_dec = np.where(y_df2 == min(y_df2))[0][0]
x_inc = np.where(y_df2 == max(y_df2))[0][0]

# plot
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, 'b', lw=3, alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(x_dec, f(x_dec), 'ro', ms= 8)
plt.plot(x_inc, f(x_inc),'ro', ms=8)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. The first point on the graph that you get is actually the point at which the first derivative stops decreasing, and so where the second derivative is (closest to) zero.

Comment: The first point on the graph is where the second derivative is not closest to zero, but is on its minimum (and a negative value). However there any way  to catch the point on the curve (should be x around 50) where the decrease start?

Comment: You mean something like `np.where(y_df1 < 0)[0][0]`? That'll give you the first index where the first derivative of `y` is negative. (Replace `< 0` by `< k` to get an arbitrary limit.)